# Moving Eclipse M2E Web App Dependencies Into Project File System

Tags: java, eclipse, web-applications, heroku, m2e

I am currently working on a web app in Eclipse that I plan to push to Heroku. I am using the maven Eclipse plugin (m2e) for downloading dependencies for my app. Maven works great except for one thing.

Maven is downloading all my dependencies into ~/.m2 which is fine except for one thing. When I push my app up to Heroku those dependencies won't go up with it, so I need the dependencies within the project file system. So my problem is finding the best way (or any way in fact) to get the dependencies into my project.

I'm still a noob so any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a maven plugin in your eclipse, you can configure this directory on:

Window - Preferences -> Maven -> User Settings

But this is not you problem, because this maven file system is just to archive your repositories and the maven don need download it everytime.

Maybe you need to configure a war plugin in yout pom.xml.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```